# R create week numbers with specified start date

Tags: r, lubridate

This seems like it should be straightforward but I cannot find a way to do this.

I have a sales cycle that begins ~ August 1 of each year and need to sum sales by week number. I need to create a "week number" field where week #1 begins on a date that I specify. Thus far I have looked at lubridate, baseR, and strftime, and I cannot find a way to change the "start" date from 01/01/YYYY to something else.

Solution needs to let me specify the start date and iterate week numbers as 7 days from the start date. The actual start date doesn't always occur on a Sunday or Monday.

EG Data Frame

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
  cycle = c("cycle2019", "cycle2019", "cycle2018", "cycle2018", "cycle2017", "cycle2017", "cycle2016", "cycle2016"),
  dates = as.POSIXct(c("2019-08-01" , "2019-08-10" ,"2018-07-31" , "2018-08-16",  "2017-08-03" , "2017-08-14" , "2016-08-05", "2016-08-29")),
  week_n = c("1", "2","1","3","1","2","1","4"))
```

I'd like the result to look like what is above - it would take the min date for each cycle and use that as a starting point, then iterate up week numbers based on a given date's distance from the cycle starting date.

Comment: When you say `~ August 1` is that because the date changes each year? Is there a predictable way to specify what that date is in a given year?

Comment: Yes, the date changes. It is *around* August 1, but could be last week of July, up through about August 5. That's why I wanted to peg the start date at whatever the minimum date was for that specific cycle. Good question though thank you for forcing me to clarify.

Comment: Gotcha. If you have a table of those dates you can join to your data. Added that step to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This *almost* works. (Doing date arithmetic gives us durations in seconds: there may be a smoother way to convert with `lubridate` tools?)

```r
secs_per_week <- 60*60*24*7
(eg_data 
    %>% group_by(cycle) 
    %>% mutate(nw=1+as.numeric(round((dates-min(dates))/secs_per_week)))
)
```

The results don't match for 2017, because there is an 11-day gap between the first and second observation ...

```r
 cycle     dates               week_n    nw
  <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>  <dbl>
5 cycle2017 2017-08-03 00:00:00 1          1
6 cycle2017 2017-08-14 00:00:00 2          3
```

Comment: It gets close yes, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite work the same as your example, but perhaps with some fiddling based on your domain experience you could adapt it:

```
library(lubridate)
eg_data %>% 
  mutate(aug1 = ymd_h(paste(str_sub(cycle, start = -4), "080100")),
         week_n2 = ceiling((dates - aug1)/ddays(7)))
```

EDIT: If you have specific known dates for the start of each cycle, it might be helpful to join those dates to your data for the calc:

```
library(lubridate)
cycle_starts <- data.frame(
  cycle = c("cycle2019", "cycle2018", "cycle2017", "cycle2016"),
  start_date = ymd_h(c(2019080100, 2018072500, 2017080500, 2016071300))
)

eg_data %>% 
  left_join(cycle_starts) %>%
  mutate(week_n2 = ceiling((dates - start_date)/ddays(7)))   


#Joining, by = "cycle"
#      cycle      dates week_n start_date week_n2
#1 cycle2019 2019-08-01      1 2019-08-01       1
#2 cycle2019 2019-08-10      2 2019-08-01       2
#3 cycle2018 2018-07-31      1 2018-07-25       1
#4 cycle2018 2018-08-16      3 2018-07-25       4
#5 cycle2017 2017-08-03      1 2017-08-05       0
#6 cycle2017 2017-08-14      2 2017-08-05       2
#7 cycle2016 2016-08-05      1 2016-07-13       4
#8 cycle2016 2016-08-29      4 2016-07-13       7
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a better answer plz post, but this works -

Take the dataframe in the example, eg_data -

```
eg_data %>%
  group_by(cycle) %>%
  mutate(
    cycle_start = as.Date(min(dates)),
    days_diff = as.Date(dates) - cycle_start, 
    week_n = days_diff / 7,
    week_n_whole = ceiling(days_diff / 7) ) -> eg_data_check
```

(First time I've answered my own question)

Answer (score 0):

```
library("lubridate")
eg_data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(cycle) %>% 
  mutate(new_week = week(dates)-31)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a concise solution using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

eg_data %>%
  group_by(cycle) %>%
  mutate(new_week = floor(as.period(ymd(dates) - ymd(min(dates))) / weeks()) + 1)
```

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   cycle [4]
  cycle     dates               week_n new_week
  <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>     <dbl>
1 cycle2019 2019-08-01 00:00:00 1             1
2 cycle2019 2019-08-10 00:00:00 2             2
3 cycle2018 2018-07-31 00:00:00 1             1
4 cycle2018 2018-08-16 00:00:00 3             3
5 cycle2017 2017-08-03 00:00:00 1             1
6 cycle2017 2017-08-14 00:00:00 2             2
7 cycle2016 2016-08-05 00:00:00 1             1
8 cycle2016 2016-08-29 00:00:00 4             4
```